# PostgreSQL >= 10 does not generate WAL if there are no transactions

Tags: postgresql, transaction-log, postgresql-10, postgresql-11

I noticed that PostgreSQL >= 10 does not generate WAL if there are no transactions.
In previous versions, PostgreSQL generated WAL at the expiration of `archive_timout`, because it wrote some empty transactions.

I want PostgreSQL to still generate WAL if no one writes to it. Does anyone know how to do this in versions starting from 10?

Comment: Why would you want that?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name to monitor streaming replication lag. Which is critical point to monitor in RDBMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That must be because of [commit 6ef2eba3f](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commit;h=6ef2eba3f57f17960b7cd4958e18aa79e357de2f):

> Skip checkpoints, archiving on idle systems.
>
> Some background activity (like checkpoints, archive timeout, standby
>   snapshots) is not supposed to happen on an idle system. Unfortunately
>   so far it was not easy to determine when a system is idle, which
>   defeated some of the attempts to avoid redundant activity on an idle
>   system.

If you really need to have regular WAL activity, the cheapest way is to have a `cron` job that runs `SELECT txid_current()` regularly.

If you want to monitor replication, it is better to measure the lag in bytes, that is immune to this problem.